# How to plot a yearly dataset in python to view trends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have a dataframe which looks like the table below with 10 records. The columns names are the years. I will like to plot the records so I can visualize the yearly trend of the data with the years as my X axis. How can I achieve this?

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
+------+------+------+------+
|   31 |   25 |   32 |   57 |
|   23 |   54 |   28 |   29 |
|   30 |   25 |   37 |   44 |
|   31 |   25 |   32 |   57 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: does `df.t.plot()` get you what you want? if you x-axis is your column labels, is each row it's own series?

Comment: @PaulH yes each row is its own series. Each row represents a record for a particular customer. What is t?

Comment: oops, I meant `df.T.plot()` (it should be capitalized)

Comment: Awesome!!! the T worked for me. How does it work please or can you send a link to go read more on it.

Comment: pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Paul H, `df.T.plot()` worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code shown as in below:

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {'2015':['31','23','30','31'],
       '2016':['25'],[54],[25],[25]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dct).melt()
df.plot(x=’Value’, y=’Year’)
plt.show()
```

If you change the view of graph you can use such as "color", "marker","markersize" parameters.